# Timezone in symfony

Tags: php, symfony, timezone

I'm trying to run new symfony project by symfony new name_project 2.7.21. Unfortunately, I keep having the error for incorrect time zone. I changed it in my C:\xampp\php\php.ini file. Do I have to change it somewhere else? Many thanks for your help

Comment: which error? in your requirements page? have you restarted the web server?

Comment: The error is: date.timezone setting must be set. Set the date.timezone setting in php.ini (like Europe/Paris). So I changed to timezone Europe/Amsterdam and I run a small check in php which shows that my dates are the same: <?php date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Amsterdam');
$script_tz = date_default_timezone_get();
if (strcmp($script_tz, ini_get('date.timezone'))){
    echo 'timezone differs from ini-set.';
} else {echo 'timezone match.';
}?> I don't know what else I can do.

Answer (score 6):

try

add in app/AppKernel.php

```
 public function __construct($environment, $debug)
{
    date_default_timezone_set( 'Europe/Warsaw' );
    parent::__construct($environment, $debug);
}
```

I had the same problem with CI system , and  that was  solution

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand, I'm quite new to this. To which appKernel shall I add it. I thought appKernel is created once I create symfony project but I cannot because of the timezone problem.

Comment: problem you described tells that there is a problem with timezone  configuration on your server . Simple way (witchout messing in server configuration)  is to  add above code in AppKernel  - that code  overwrite wrong configuration setting.  And yes you need to add it in appkernel that was created when you created symfony project.  (you don't edit  appkernel from browser ,  you need to tu use text/code editor)

Comment: I think I'm getting closer but it still doesn't work. I changed it by nano editor and I added this function to appKernel... any other ideas?

Comment: date.timezone setting must be set. Set the date.timezone setting in php.ini (like Europe/Paris) . I also made a check and it says the times match <?php

phpinfo();


date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Amsterdam');

$script_tz = date_default_timezone_get();

if (strcmp($script_tz, ini_get('date.timezone'))){
    echo 'Script timezone differs from ini-set timezone.';
} else {
    echo 'Script timezone and ini-set timezone match.';
}
?>

Comment: I solved it, I added timezone to only apache2 php.ini file and I had to add to cli php.ini as well. After I did it works. Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 5):

If your Symfony version is "^4.*" you can set your global timeZone in project/public/index.php

`$kernel = new Kernel($_SERVER['APP_ENV'], (bool) $_SERVER['APP_DEBUG']);
date_default_timezone_set( 'Europe/Moscow' );
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();`

PHP supported timezone list below

https://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.europe.php

Answer (score 2):

**Ubuntu**

Though I had date.timezone set in the /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini file.

I had to Set the date.timezone = "Asia/Calcutta" in the php.ini file which was in the cli directory.

/etc/php5/cli/php.ini

This solved it for me...

Answer (score 0):

If editing the ini file doesn't work, make sure you are editing the correct one. Check which ini file php is loading by outputting the `phpinfo` results.

Otherwise, you can hard-code the timezone in `app.php` and `app_dev.php`

See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

Answer (score 0):

Hey so I spent a lot of time chasing this down so here's what worked.  To find the real php.ini that you need to change go to Terminal and run the following:
`php -i | grep "php.ini"`

You'll get a path like this: `Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /etc`

When you go to that directory you may find that you, in fact, have no `php.ini` file at all but instead have something named `php.ini.default` !!!

Copy that bad boy in Terminal like so: `sudo cp php.ini.default php.ini`

Then open up your new `php.ini` file and edit the `date.timezone = "Europe/Paris"`

IMPORTANT!!!  RESTART YOUR LOCAL SERVER!

Then go back to Terminal and run Symfony's complaining-ass validator like so: `php my_project_name/bin/symfony_requirements`